# A Puzzle That Paddles In Lines

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> There's a flower that grows in myriad places
>   It's in a disease, it's found upon faces
>   It's found in the one who accuses a thief
>   It's found in the one who switches belief
>   It's found in all those who call themselves straight
>   As well as a very short timespan to wait.
>   It may be a hip or a drink that you boil.
>   Search in the sundew and the stuff made from oil.

The answer is a single English word.

Comment: It's so refreshing to see a riddle that not only scans well, but also has a reasonable unambiguous solution.  Thanks for a great example of what a riddle should be!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Rose?

Although I'm still figuring out the specific answers to all the clues.

---

> There's a flower that grows in myriad places  : [Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose) is found in multitude of varieties and has thorns on it!
>
>
>  It's in a disease, it's found upon faces  - AtherosclEROSis (I was thinking ROSEola and rosy cheeks)
>  It's found in the one who accuses a thief - pROSEcutor
>  It's found in the one who switches belief - pROSElytism
>  It's found in all those who call themselves straight - heteROSExual
>  As well as a very short timespan to wait. -  micROSEcond
>  It may be a hip or a drink that you boil. - ROSEhip (I was thinking tea rose for the second half)
>  Search in the sundew and the stuff made from oil. - dROSEra, keROSEne
>
>  As Deusovi points out, the title can be restated as "A Puzzle That Rows In Rows", punning on the solution.

Comment: Almost there. Check the spelling of your disease. Missing a couple of clues. (The title, for instance.)

Comment: Aah, interesting :)

Comment: @HughMeyers May I help him out?

Comment: @ABcDexter I have no problem with that.

Comment: The title is "A Puzzle that Rows in Rows", to put it slightly differently.

Comment: @Deusovi Yes exactly :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing my post. I tried without success, not sure how is it done.

Comment: @HughMeyers It's in a disease, it's found upon faces - AtherosclEROSis (I was thinking ROSEola) - I thought these are two separate clues. I'm pretty sure the atherosclerosis won't show on the face so yours seems better.

Comment: You add two spaces at the end of a line to preserve the line break. Just one of those little things.

Comment: Is the disease ROSEola?

Comment: Man -- I thought it was this answer not because the word showed up, but because 'rose' could reasonably refer to most of the lines (rosy cheeks; coming from disease, from lying/emotion/hiding, can come quickly, rosehip drink). I didn't think about the spelling of the words themselves.

Answer (score 6):

There's a flower that grows in myriad places

> [Moleflower Pot as in this](https://in.pinterest.com/pin/534028468284635317/)

---

It's in a disease, it's found upon faces

> [Mole](http://www.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/guide/moles-freckles-skin-tags) as that on a face.

---

It's found in the one who accuses a thief

> [A saying in Hindi has it](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101219101653AApsHsT)

---

It's found in the one who switches belief

> [Mole as a spy..](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(espionage))

---

It's found in all those who call themselves straight

> Is it the [Mole of organic matter found in every living being](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit))?

---

As well as a very short timespan to wait.

> [Mole, the animal has about 4 years of life span.](http://a-z-animals.com/animals/mole/)

---

It may be a hip or a drink that you boil.

> Here I am struck!

---

Search in the sundew and the stuff made from oil.

> [Mexican Mole sauce.](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/76662/mexican-mole-sauce/)

Comment: you could try 'moleasc soup', and moles 'paddle' (furrow) in lines, so good one!

Comment: An upvote for ingenuity! Moleskins are a type of trousers, which are sort of hip related. Could straight be interpreted as a reference to "orthomolecular"? Am I deliberately trying to make my own puzzle too broad? Who knows. (I might go for the soap plant - amole - as the flower as well.)

Comment: Haha xD  @HughMeyers You made my day, thanks :D